# PayPal's JavaScript API is forcing “Shipping same as billing address”?

Tags: javascript, api, checkbox, paypal

#### Sandbox

First be advised there is a [testing sandbox provided by PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client) for you to try these code samples.

#### What I have tried

```js
return actions.order.create({
  purchase_units: [{
    amount: { value: '88.44' },
    shipping: {
      name: { full_name: 'Ship Name' },
      address: {
        address_line_1: 'Ship Address',
        address_line_2: '',
        admin_area_2: 'Ship City',
        admin_area_1: 'SC',
        postal_code: 'SHP ZIP',
        country_code: 'US',
      },
    }
  }],
  payer: {
    name: { given_name: 'Bill', surname: 'Name' },
    address: {
      address_line_1: 'Bill Address',
      address_line_2: '',
      admin_area_2: 'Bill City',
      admin_area_1: 'MS',
      postal_code: 'BIL 0H0',
      country_code: 'US',
    }
  },
})
```

#### Reproducing the issue

Click [image: the PayPal checkout button]

Then, in the popup, click [image: Pay with Credit or Debit Card]

You will notice the correct billing option is present. [image: Billing Address is Bill Name/Address]

However, the Shipping Address is hidden behind the checkbox. [image: Shipping same as billing address]

This could lead to the user accidentally shipping the product to the wrong address!

#### How can I fix this?

That checkbox should ideally be unchecked because we are clearly passing a different address in the source code above.

#### As a side note

If the user does uncheck the box, [they do get the correct address.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIhak.png)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to "uncheck" the box by default. Either the address is changeable or it isn't.

See the documentation: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-order_application_context

application_context -> shipping_preference -> SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS